# Reverse a linked list recursively

Tags: c++, linked-list

My recursion skill is pretty rusty. I've been thinking about this problem and searched the forum for a long time but still cannot understand.I am trying to implement reverse a linked list using recursion .why is my reverse function not working?

When I am trying to see the reversed linkedlist it is only printing `5` as a result whereas the result should be `1 0 2 3 4 5`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
};
void reverse(node* head)
{
   if (!head || !(head -> next))
    {return ;}
 reverse(head->next);
    head->next->next=head;
    head->next=NULL;
  
    
}
void print(node* n){
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<n->data<<" ";
        n=n->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
void insert(node** head,int x)
{
    node* one=new node();
    one->data=x;
    one->next= *head;
    *head=one;
}
int main()
{   node* head=NULL;
     insert(&head,1);
     insert(&head,0);
      insert(&head,2);
       insert(&head,3);
        insert(&head,4);
         insert(&head,5);
         reverse(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Naming your parameter `node* head` may be deceiving you, since every node of the list is passed as that parameter, not just the head.  Changing the name may cause you to rethink what `head->next=NULL;` is doing.

Comment: In what specific way(s) is this "not working"?

Comment: when I am trying to see the reversed linkedlist it is only printing 5 as a result  whereas the result should be 1 0 2 3 4 5

Comment: `void reverse(node* head)` does not allow head to be changed in the caller.

Comment: so what should I do instead?

Comment: If your recursion is rusty, try removing the recursive line `reverse(head->next);` and see if you can figure out how calling the function causes `head->next` to become null.

Comment: @drescherjm But if you use `void reverse(node* & head)` then the recursive call doesn't work. It would be better to use `node * reverse(node * head)` and `head = reverse(head);`

Comment: still not able to understand  how to make the recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes the `head` pointer by *value* so the caller will never see its `head` pointer change, yet it is clear that when a list is reversed, the `head` pointer should point to the node that previously was the tail node.

One way to solve this is to use pass-by-reference (using `&`), and then make sure you move the `head` pointer to the last node in the original list. This you can do by performing `head = head->next` in every recursive call until the base case is hit.

Corrected function:

```
void reverse(node* &head)
{
    if (head == nullptr || head -> next == nullpr) {
        return;
    }
    node* tail = head; // current head will be the tail in the reversed list
    head = head->next; // head should walk to the end of the list
    // This will reverse the sublist, and make the head reference the last node
    reverse(head);
    // Make tail of the sublist (tail->next) point to the new tail
    tail->next->next = tail; 
    tail->next = nullptr;
}
```